# why does perl constructor not initialize the package(class) variables

Tags: perl, class-variables

when perl constructor is called ,class reference is passed to the new function but constructor doesn't initialize class variables like java or c++ does.Instead it creates a new Hash and blesses it in class reference and returns it.This creates the problem that subroutines can't directly refer to variables they have to use the implicit reference passed.

The below code will highlight the issue:-

```
package foo;
use strict;
my $var1;
my $var2;
my $var3;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {
        var1 => shift,
        var2 => shift,
        var3 => shift
      };

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;

      }

sub method {

        my $self = shift;
        print(
            "variable value are $self->{var1},$self->{var2},$self->{var3}";
       #how to directly refer to var1 declared above? instead of self->{var1} 
       }
```

clearly the package method has to use the reference self to use var1,var2,var3 
which is are not the package variables but only the hash's objects.

1:-what this means is in perl there is no way to initialize the package variables??
2:-if i initialize them explicitly in some method,would they have one copy for all objects or different copy per object

Comment: That's just how it is in Perl. Package scope variables are like class variables in Java. - There are several OO tutorials in the Perl distribution. Read these for starters.

Comment: The example code is broken. It has unbalanced braces and has the `new` method calling the `new` method. It would probably be easier to understand this question if the code were clearer.

Comment: yeah corrected that!!!thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to use package variables is to declare them with `our`. Outside the package, you can refer to them by qualifying the variable name with the package.

```
package foo;
our ($var1, $var2, $var3) = (5, 42, "bar");
sub new { bless { var4 => $_[1] }, $_[0] }
...
1;


package main;
use foo;
$obj = foo->new(19);   # instance of foo
print "Instance variable is $obj->{var4}\n";    # 19
print "Package variable is $foo::var1\n";       #  5
```

Comment: Thanks,outside the method can we change the value of the package variables.??

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, the package variables, eg: the `my $var1` at the top of your file, are not instance variables.  They correspond to Static variables in languages like Java or C#.  In Perl it is conventional to use `$self` where other languages use `this`.  Some languages, like Java, let you omit the use of `this` when referring to member variables.  Some, like JavaScript and Perl do not.

If you're asking how to initialize the static variables, you can certainly do that by just assigning to them when you create them.

```
package foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $created_at = localtime();

sub created_at {
  return $created_at;
}

sub new {
  my($pkg,$p1,$p2) = @_;
  my $self = {
    prop1 => $p1,
    prop2 => $p2
  };
  return bless $self, $pkg;
}

# you can create accessors, think of these as getters and setters, if you pass a value it is set
sub prop1 { my($self,$v) = @_; $self->{prop1} = $v if @_>1; return $self->{prop1}; } 
sub prop2 { my($self,$v) = @_; $self->{prop2} = $v if @_>1; return $self->{prop2}; }

sub method {
  my($self) = @_;
  print "prop1=",$self->{prop1},"; prop2=",$self->{prop2},"\n";
}

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

print "created_at = ",foo->created_at,"\n";

my $f = foo->new("banana","apple");

print "f->created_at = ", $f->created_at,"\n";
$f->method();
$f->prop1('orange');
$f->method();
```

This is an older way to handle OO in Perl, based on Perl5's initial support for Objects. If you're more familiar with other Object systems, you might want to have a look at Perl's [Moose](http://moose.iinteractive.com/en/about.html) libraries, which provide more of what you might be used to.

HTH,

Kyle

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.The word static almost clears all the doubts.
in calling package one can use setters on these static fields to set the value dynamically.How can we create instance variables in perl??

Comment: Hi @RahulKumar in my example, `prop1` and `prop2` are instance variables.  Are you familiar with Javascript?   Objects have very similar semantics in JS and Perl.  `$self->{prop1}` _is_ a member variable.  You can 'create' new ones at any time (again just like in JS) by assigning it `$self->{prop99}`

Comment: Hi @kyle ,I understand that prop1 and prop2 arer keys to the hash you created which got blessed into the reference ,they can be thought as instance variables .to access these again i have to use $self which is passed in the function .what i wanted to ask is is there a way that package variables can be declared as instance variables??or package variables are always static???

Comment: Yes, anything outside of `$self` and outside of a `sub` is a package variable.